# problem with installing app in the device

Tags: android

I have an android app. (built for 1.5) while installing it on my device it creates no error, but while running it, it says "the application is not installed in your phone"..
can any one help me...?
I have tried this  installing after uninstalling it for many times...

**Manifest file:**

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              package="com.android.testapp"
              android:versionCode="1"
              android:versionName="1.0">


            <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
                <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="WelcomeScreen">
                    <intent-filter>
                        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                    </intent-filter>
                </activity>


<activity android:name="Untitled1"></activity>
     <activity android:name="Welcome"></activity>

            </application>
    </manifest>
```

Comment: That's weird. which version your phone has? although all of Droids are backward compatible, AFAIK

Comment: I have tried it on both 1.5 and 2.2 sdk devices..

Comment: Hey Rahul, the package name should not be "com.xx.xx" ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its an application error. In application there is an manifest file in which we pass two actions ACTION_LAUNCHER and ACTION_MAIN which is not write there thats why this application says "the application is not installed in your phone" please verify from the android developer of this application. IF you have manifest file of this please write down here. i will correct this.

If this answer is useful to you then please tick that this answer is useful to you.

Comment: I think the problem is ...at first my starting activity was a different one, then later I changed it..will that create some trouble..

Comment: <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /> after writing this you can launch your application if the application already saying this then you have to uninstall the application first after that install it. put .WelcomeScreen in activity tag in android:name

Comment: I have tried installing and Uninstalling ...for many time..but it still says the same thing

Comment: please send the WelcomeScreen.java class

Comment: the welcome screen class just have a button,which have a i=onclick event. The onclick event have an intent to the Untitled class. My app runs perfectly on the emulator

Comment: please check the logcat and send whats the actual error you face

Comment: But while installing in the device how can I get the logcat details. I have no trouble in running the app in my emulator

Comment: change the package name of your application from com.android to com.something whatever you want then change it into manifest also. and check what the min sdk you used and what sdk you used.

Comment: put <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" /> when application tag closed

Answer (score 1):

Have you got your package name correct? It will be looking for a different application if your package name in the Manifest does not match that of your project

Answer (score 0):

Who or what tells you "is not installed"?
If you have a shortcut on the home screen, this may become stale and you can get this message.
Try going to the list of apps and starting it from there.

I also see potential that the "com.android.*" package you show is causing issues, as this package may be reserved (at least it is not good practice to use it).

Comment: I had installed the first version of this app in an emulator in a different machine, but after that I had made a new activity, that will be the stating one(welcome screen). In the earlier version I was having a different activity as the starting one...While installing the latest version on a device or emulator(in a different machine) it doesnt show any errors, but when I tap the launch icon a toast message appears as "this application is not installed in your phone"....

Comment: Go to the application management menu and make sure it is completely de-installed from there and then try re-installing.

Comment: I had tried installing and Uninstalling several times...but still it says the same thing....

Comment: While clicking the open button after installing , I get the following message "The application Package installer(process com.android.packageinstaller) has stopped unexpectedly"...

Comment: Do you have access at the logcat and could paste the messages from install time here? This sounds a lot like issues with the manifest or with signing of the app or such.

Answer (score 0):

Issue solved,
I just copied and deleted the below lines from the manifest file and pasted it again  in the same place ...
I dont know how it solved the issue but it just solved it....

```
<application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
                    <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="WelcomeScreen">
                        <intent-filter>
                            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                        </intent-filter>
                    </activity>
```